# Is it possible to create a local char array in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've recently started picking up coding and I'm working through an online course which teaches you how to set up a text based "hacker" game.

I am currently trying to find a way to have the text appear to be typed out and the best method I found was by using coroutines and char arrays.

The only issue I run into is if I try to change what the system types out, it reuses the data from when I initially created the char array. I'm just curious if there is a way to localize the array itself in my code below, or if I have to consider rewriting some of it and finding a better solution.

```
void Start()
{
    currentScreen = Screen.Prologue;
    StartCoroutine("TypePrologue");
}

IEnumerator TypePrologue()
{
    foreach (char letter in OpeningMessage.ToCharArray())
    {
        Terminal.WriteLine(Indent += letter.ToString());
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        Terminal.ClearScreen();
    }
    Terminal.WriteLine(OpeningMessage);
    yield break;
}
```

Just to clarify, my issue is when I change the variable OpeningMessage and call the function again later or if I call a different function that is identical in every way other than the OpeningMessage variable, the new characters stack on top of what I had before, making a bit of a jumbled mess.

Thanks in advance! I'm sure it could be cleaned up a bit but I'm more concerned about getting a working program first.

Comment: if i understand you: you want to know if an hacker could detect the content of openingMessage?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't reuse the same object, when you send message - you just send it and then allocate new message at the sender...
Otherwise you need some synchronization mechanism

Comment: Could you post the full code? We don't see what happens with `OpeningMessage` in other places .. or how that `Terminal` works

Comment: Where is `OpeningMessage` declared and initialised?

Comment: You should clear the terminal before writing to it again if you say you're having overlapping issues